# How to use "ConvertTo-Html -CssUri"?

Tags: html, css, powershell

I stuck with a  simple task to convert any list of a process into HTML file with CSS after several updates (`Update-Help`), I  finally outputted  HTML successfully, with the command (`Invoke-Expression .\test.html`), but without CSS style added to it, technically the file **test.css** doesn't exist.

Could you clarify what possibly could be wrong, I just used the short example from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sztCBTSXsEA) where the whole process was perfectly fine.

My code:

```
gsv | Select Name, Status | ConvertTo-Html -CSSUri c:\test.css | Out-File test.html
Invoke-Expression .\test.html
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///c:/test.css" />
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Status</th></tr>
<tr><td>ABBYY.Licensing.Lingvo.Desktop.14.0</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>AdobeARMservice</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>AGSService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>AJRouter</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>ALG</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>AppIDSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Appinfo</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>AppMgmt</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>AppReadiness</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>AppXSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Archos Sepang Modem Device Helper</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASGT</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>aspnet_state</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>AudioEndpointBuilder</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Audiosrv</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>AxInstSV</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>BDESVC</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>BFE</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>BITS</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>BrokerInfrastructure</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Browser</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>BthHFSrv</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>bthserv</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>CDPSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>CertPropSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>ClipSVC</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>COMSysApp</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>CoreMessagingRegistrar</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>CryptSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>CscService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DcomLaunch</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>DcpSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>defragsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DeviceAssociationService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DeviceInstall</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DevQueryBroker</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dhcp</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DiagTrack</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Disc Soft Ultra Bus Service</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DmEnrollmentSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>dmwappushservice</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dnscache</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>DoSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>dot3svc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DPS</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>DsmSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>DsSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Eaphost</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>EFS</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>embeddedmode</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>EntAppSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>EventLog</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>EventSystem</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fax</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>fdPHost</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>FDResPub</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>fhsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>FontCache</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>FontCache3.0.0.0</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>fussvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>GfExperienceService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>gpsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>gupdate</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>gupdatem</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>hidserv</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>HomeGroupProvider</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>icssvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>IEEtwCollectorService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>IKEEXT</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>iphlpsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>KeyIso</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>KtmRm</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>LanmanServer</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>LanmanWorkstation</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>lfsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>LicenseManager</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>lltdsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>lmhosts</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>LSM</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>MapsBroker</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>MpsSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>MSDTC</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>MSiSCSI</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>msiserver</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NcaSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NcbService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>NcdAutoSetup</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Netlogon</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Netman</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>netprofm</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>NetSetupSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NetTcpPortSharing</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NgcCtnrSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NgcSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>NlaSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>nsi</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>NvNetworkService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>NvStreamSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>nvsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>p2pimsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>p2psvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PcaSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>PeerDistSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PerfHost</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PhoneSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>pla</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PlugPlay</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>PNRPAutoReg</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PNRPsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>PolicyAgent</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Power</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>PrintNotify</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>ProfSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>QWAVE</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>RasAuto</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>RasMan</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>RemoteAccess</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>RemoteRegistry</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>RetailDemo</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>RpcEptMapper</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>RpcLocator</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>RpcSs</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SamSs</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SCardSvr</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>ScDeviceEnum</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Schedule</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SCPolicySvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDRSVC</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>seclogon</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SENS</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SensorDataService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SensorService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SensrSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Service KMSELDI</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SessionEnv</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SharedAccess</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>ShellHWDetection</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>smphost</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SmsRouter</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SNMPTRAP</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Spooler</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>sppsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SQLWriter</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SSDPSRV</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SstpSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>StateRepository</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Stereo Service</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>stisvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>StorSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>svsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>swprv</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>SysMain</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>SystemEventsBroker</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>TabletInputService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>TapiSrv</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Te.Service</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>TermService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Themes</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>TieringEngineService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>tiledatamodelsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>TimeBroker</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>TrkWks</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>TrustedInstaller</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>tzautoupdate</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>UI0Detect</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>UmRdpService</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>upnphost</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>UserManager</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>UsoSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>VaultSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>vds</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicguestinterface</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicheartbeat</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmickvpexchange</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicrdv</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicshutdown</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmictimesync</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicvmsession</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>vmicvss</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>VSS</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>VSStandardCollectorService140</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>W32Time</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WalletService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wbengine</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WbioSrvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wcmsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>wcncsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WcsPlugInService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WdiServiceHost</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WdiSystemHost</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WdNisSvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WebClient</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wecsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WEPHOSTSVC</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wercplsupport</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WerSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WiaRpc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WinDefend</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WinHttpAutoProxySvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>Winmgmt</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WinRM</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WlanSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wlidsvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wmiApSrv</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WMPNetworkSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>workfolderssvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WPDBusEnum</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>WpnService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wscsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WSearch</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WSService</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>wuauserv</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>wudfsvc</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WwanSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>XblAuthManager</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>XblGameSave</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>XboxNetApiSvc</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide evidence.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///c:/test.css" />`

Comment: Does the file not exist? Are the styles not applied?

Comment: How can I deal with this line :PS C:\webtest> get-content .\test.css
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\webtest\test.css' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-content .\test.css
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\webtest\test.css:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

PS C:\webtest>

Comment: Powershell applied link href line into HTML, but the CSS doesn't exist as CSS file in the folder on hard disk. In the video I watched  it does. The author demonstrates the CSS file using command Get-content.

Answer (score 0):

I will note that the file c:\test.css will not be embedded into the html file when you do this. So if you use this to make an html file and move it, the css file must move with it. A typical www directory would look like this:

```
\css\styles.css
index.html
```

and the head of the html file would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
...
```

So in this case, the style.css file is not a static path.

Comment: Right! I could create the CSS folder with CSS file manually, to apply it to HTML, but my point was to automate the process, I thought the Powershell can create the CSS folder and completely functional CSS file with simple rules inside. Probably I was misunderstood the video from YouTube.

Comment: It can, but convertto-html does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use this [ConvertToHtml](https://github.com/TravisEz13/ConvertToHtml) module on GitHub.

I'm not trying to self-promote, but I wrote this because the built-in PowerShell cmdlet had limited formatting functionality for the table and it sounds like this maybe closer to what you want.

I mainly use it to send reports in outlook and last time I tested Outlook 2013 only seems to work with inline styles.  So, the module currently uses inline style, but if you make a PR or file an issue (and I happen to get free time), It sounds like a useful feature.

The CI system has very simple example artifacts produced to verify the build is good.  [Examples.zip](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/lch3g279trhy0n7e/artifacts/examples.zip)

The docs are currently rather sparse.  There is a JSON description of how you want the output to look.  I can update the readme if you are interested in using the module, file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @Alan Install-Module converttohtml -Scope CurrentUser -repository converttohtml   should resolve that error.

Comment: @Alan you can not register a repository twice.  Just the  updated install command should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS file doesn't exist already you need to create it before you can use it in an HTML file:

```
@'
table {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
'@ | Set-Content 'test.css'

... | ConvertTo-Html -CSSUri 'test.css' | Out-File 'test.html'
```

Better yet, don't bother writing the stylesheet to a file  if you want to create everything on the fly anyway. Instead insert the styles as a header into your generated HTML:

```
$style = @'
<style type="text/css">
table {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
'@

... | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-File 'test.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

But sometimes you want to have the stylesheet in a separate CSS file.  This is easier to edit or replace. Then you could simply read the CSS file in the script and store it in a $header variable. This can then be processed in the ConvertTo-Html command. Here is an example.

CSS-File:

```
/* MyCssFile.css */
table {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

PowerShell-Script:

```
...
$Css = Get-Content -Path '.\MyCssFile.css' -Raw
$style= ("<style>`n") + $Css + ("`n</style>")
...
... | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-File -Path 'test.html'
```

The advantage here is, you have all the html code in a single file. This is convenient, for example, for reports that are to be sent by email.